# Access object everywhere in the application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In a spring boot application, I read serial port with [serialPuntit](https://github.com/RishiGupta12/SerialPundit) librairie.

Thread is started via onApplicationEvent.

That work fine.

```
@Component
public class ScanRead implements Runnable {

    Thread thrd;
    boolean suspended;
    boolean stopped;

    String port = "/dev/ttyUSB0";

    final protected static char[] hexArray = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();

    public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
        for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) {
            int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
            hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
            hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
        }
        return new String(hexChars);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {

            while (true) {

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                SerialComManager scm = new SerialComManager();
                long handle = scm.openComPort(port, true, false, true);
                byte[] dataRead = {};

                scm.configureComPortData(handle, DATABITS.DB_8, STOPBITS.SB_1, PARITY.P_NONE, BAUDRATE.B9600, 0);
                scm.configureComPortControl(handle, FLOWCONTROL.NONE, 'x', 'x', false, false);

                long context = scm.createBlockingIOContext();

                for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
                    dataRead = scm.readBytesBlocking(handle, 1, context);
                    if (dataRead != null) {
                        sb.append(bytesToHex(dataRead));
                    }
                }

                System.out.println(sb.toString());

                scm.unblockBlockingIOOperation(context);
                scm.destroyBlockingIOContext(context);
                scm.closeComPort(handle);

                Thread.sleep(50);

                synchronized (this) {
                    while (suspended) {
                        wait();
                    }
                    if (stopped) {
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
        } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
            System.out.println(thrd.getName() + " interrupted.");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ScanRead.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    synchronized void stop() {
        stopped = true;
        suspended = false;
        notify();
    }

    synchronized void suspend() {
        suspended = true;
    }

    synchronized void resume() {
        suspended = false;
        notify();
    }

}


@Component
public class ScanApplicationStartup implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {
  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(final ApplicationReadyEvent event) {

    ScanRead sc = new ScanRead();

    sc.run();
  }

}
```

Only downside, can't use another SerialComManager in another place in the application to read on the same port.

I search a way to init SerialComManager and use it everywhere in the application.

Any suggestion.

Comment: Create a bean add getter method and return this object, bean by default are prototype (same instance is returned everytime), you can use this anywhere in your spring project.

Answer (score 0):

Define a bean within your app configuration class:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public SerialComManager getSerialComManager() {
        return new SerialComManager();
    }
}
```

After that you'll be able to `Autowire` instances into needed classes:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

@Component
public class ScanRead {
    @Autowired
    private SerialComManager scm;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // ...
        long handle = scm.openComPort(port, true, false, true);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Note that strange things start to happen if you mix autowiring with static contexts, so I'd avoid that if you can.

Comment: don't know if it's possible to do more ting in the getSerialComManager, like set default value to openComPort.

Comment: @roberttrudel Sure. There's nothing special about that method, it's just plain-old java code; you can do anything there that you would do elsewhere. The only thing `@Bean` does is tell Spring to take the result of that method and add it to the Spring context. That way, every time you ask for a bean of that type you're getting that very same instance.

Comment: ok, in fact, can't do openport there, because need handle value for other method...  So I think before doing my other read, in the suspend method of the tread, i will need to closeport and in the resume open it. Will need to put context and handle value global to the tread. How to access ScanRead to be able to suspend and resume thread in my controller? Need to be same instance then the one in onApplicationEvent... maybe need to change that.